# Iphone dev - Multiview app with storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios

I have seen some tutorials about iphone development, but they're before ARC and before storyboard it seems.

The guy creates a switch that will switch between two views.
A class with a blue background, and a class with a red background.

How would you do this in IOS5 with storyboard?

I've heard about segues, but they get a 'back' button, which the guy in the tutorial didnt get - he simply changed between views my tapping the switch/button.

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You better go through this tutorials to understand how to develop app in IOS 5. The tutorials, which you have already seen are for ios4 and prior to it. Also you can use those in IOS 5 too. But Storyboard is much easier than XIB.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_5_Development_Essentials

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboarding_%28iPhone_iOS_5%29

Anyway @dew given you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 View Controllers into your storyboard and then embed in navigation controller. After you create some button in one view, you just gotta ctrl-drag it to the other view and select push, that should do it. Or simply chech out this tutorial http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/ :)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest watching the first 2 or 3 lectures of Stanford's CS193P introductory iPhone programming course.  It's free and will start you off on the right foot.  It's also targeted for iOS5 and Xcode 4.  Check it out at:
http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255

To answer your question, moving between view controllers is usually done using a container controller or pushing view controllers 'modally'.  I would suggest reading the View Controller Programming Guide put out by apple for an overview of how these things work.

In iOS5 you can use storyboards to set-up segues (as you suggested).  They don't always 'give you a back' button, only when you segue between view controllers within a navigation controller.  You can have a button push a view controller onto a screen by setting up target-action.

Again, the iTunesU lectures will cover all this.  Check it out!